# Query build to find records where all of a series of records have a value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let me explain a little bit about what I am trying to do because I dont even know the vocab to use to ask. I have an Access 2016 database that records staff QA data. When a staff member misses a QA we assign a job aid that explains the process and they can optionally send back a worksheet showing they learned about what was missed. If they do all of these ina  3 month period they get a credit on their QA score. So I have a series of records all of whom have a date we assigned the work(RA1) and MAY have a work returned date(RC1). [image]

In the below image "lavalleer" has earned the credit because both of her sheets got returned. "maduncn" Did not earn the credit because he didn't do one. 
I want to create a query that returns to me only the people that are like "lavalleer". I tried hitting google and searched here and access.programmers.co.uk but I'm only coming up with instructions to use Not null statements. That wouldn't work for me because if I did a IS Not Null on "maduncn" I would get the 4 records but it would exclude the null.

What I need to do is build a query where I can see staff that have dates in ALL of their RC1 fields. If any of their RC1 fields are blank I dont want them to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE NOT UserLogin IN (SELECT UserLogin FROM tablename WHERE RCI IS NULL);`

Comment: June do you agree with whatever edit that guy made. The code as I see just hangs access,

Comment: There was no change to the SQL, just how it displayed in answer. Syntax is correct. What is you actual attempted SQL?

Comment: Actually it doesn't hang. It takes 4-5 minutes to run the query though. (2-3 for the progress bar to even show which is why I thought it hangs.) Because this is a value that will never change I may just run the report quarterly and record the results in a table instead of running it live on request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `not exists` clause with a correlated subquery, e.g.

```
select t.* from YourTable t where not exists 
(select 1 from YourTable u where t.userlogin = u.userlogin and u.rc1 is null)
```

Here, `select 1` is used purely for optimisation - we don't care what the query returns, just that it has records (or doesn't have records).

---

Or, you could use a `left join` to exclude those users for which there is a null `rc1` record, e.g.:

```
select t.* from YourTable t left join
(select u.userlogin from YourTable u where u.rc1 is null) v on t.userlogin = v.userlogin
where v.userlogin is null
```

---

In all of the above, change all occurrences of `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Comment: It works in my brief testing - `exists` is valid MS Access SQL.

Comment: Okay, got past syntax error. Think IN() is simpler and adequate for this particular situation.